# Are subjects joined by "and" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Please, explain me should we refer to the subject as singular or plural, when there are multiple subjects in one sentence joined by the conjunction "and". 
I have the sentence as an example. Can we consider the subjects an individual or refer to unite element? It has confused me:

> Problem resolution and elimination of root cause help to lower the
>   number of incidents.

Comment: Yes. Use the plural.

Comment: It's often just a stylistic choice. In your example, plural is *probably* more likely, but singular is perfectly acceptable. FWIW, Americans seem to be far more wedded to "strict logic" than Brits in this respect...

Comment: AmE favours plural over singular by 2:1 with, say, [early diagnosis and treatment **are** (essential),](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=early+diagnosis+and+treatment+is%2Cearly+diagnosis+and+treatment+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearly%20diagnosis%20and%20treatment%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cearly%20diagnosis%20and%20treatment%20are%3B%2Cc0). But BrE apparently uses both forms about equally often. Personally, I'm a Brit, and I actually *prefer* singular with that one.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

***AND*** is a conjunction.

It is "used as a function word to indicate connection or addition especially of items within the same class"
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and).

So we should use the ***plural verb form*** after the phrase with the conjunction as in the phrase there are two items at least.